# Storing short audio clips in a database temporarily?

Tags: database, audio, web

What's a good solution to the following problem -

I have 10 second audio clips at 44.1kHz. This makes the files (.ogg or .wav format) something like 7056000 bits (10secs * 44.1*10^3 samples/sec * 16 bit/sample (e.g. PCM) (??)) or say 0.85 MB. BTW if my back-of-the-envelope calculations are off, please correct.

Anyways, I've got these audio clips. I want to save them in a web database and retrieve them as quickly as possible to send to the requesting client. Long-term storage isn't much of an issue.

Given what I want to do, what modern database technology should I use to do this? Will I be uploading the files to a repository and just saving their file paths in the DB? Then have clients download them when requested? Sorry for the broad scope, but this is for a web project.

Answer (score 1):

I use Azure Storage blobs for almost the same thing. Its super cheap, way cheaper than any db solution would be.

Answer (score 1):

So basically your question is where is the best place to store short clips & basically BLOB (**B** inary **L** arge **OB** ject) data in a database or simply a file pointer in a database that refers to a file system or even a URL?

In my opinion, storing binary data in a database is never a good idea. It complicates the DB, makes database backups & recovery painful. And puts it all at risk if the DB crashes. Especially if the data you are working with grows & grows.

I would recommend simply using the database to store file paths.  Or perhaps just the filenames with your codebase logic handling the path logic to some extent.  Just anything to get the basic location of the clips in the DB.

The clips themselves should be stored on the filesystem. It will not be any more taxing or faster/slower than the DB. And a better longterm scalability setup.

The DB does what it does best.  The filesystem does what it does best.  And your code melds the two to balance the two.